# How to dynamically change accelerated While the animation running in Android?

Tags: android, nineoldandroids

I am using nineoldandroid.

**Q:**
How to change the animation playback time after the animation begins to accelerate animation ends? In other words，How to change the duration?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Interpolator in your animation like this one:

```
anim.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
```

Source: [Setting Interpolators](http://cogitolearning.co.uk/?p=1019)